# Один view-элемент поверх другого в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Использую в макете ConstaintLayout, появилась нужда наложить один view элемент поверх другого, возможно ли такое в ConstraintLayout?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно не программно

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса, можете конкретнее написать?

Comment: видите большую кнопку она загораживает тескт и мне надо сделать так чтобы текст был как бы над кнопкой

Comment: @Vennic смотрите наверх

Answer (score 1):

Для этого используется разметка RelativeLayout. Находящиеся в ней элементы можно накладывать друг на друга.

Ссылка на разметку - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/relativelayout.php

Под ваш измененный вопрос - https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/489-urok-180-constraintlayout-osnovy.html

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/constraintlayout.php

Comment: а как это сделать

Comment: @danchik202020 обновил